# Help with Bayes's theory

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I know how to use this form of the Bayes's theory :

$P(A | B) = P(A ∩ B)/ P(B)$

But how do I use?:

$P (A | B,C) = P (B | A,C) P(A | C)/ P(B | C)$

What does the comma mean?
I know its a simple question but I really need to know the answer.

Comment: Comma in this context usually means **and**. So $\Pr(A|B,C)$ means $\Pr(A|(B\cap C))$.

Comment: This seems to be almost the same question as the two questions you posted previously: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705495/monty-hall-and-the-bayes-theory and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705472/how-do-i-use-this-form-of-the-bayess-theory

Comment: "What does the comma mean?" Is this a joke? You have already been explained what the comma means.

Answer (score 1):

The comma usually means "and" so P(A|B,C) is "probability that A happens given that B **and** C happens"

Comment: thank you but do you know the detailed steps

Answer (score 1):

If $P(A|B,C)$ means the probability that $A$ happens assuming both $B$ and $C$, it is just $P(A|B\cap C)$ written differently.

Now you can just use definition several times:
$$\begin{align}
P(A|B\cap C)
&=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}=\\
&=\frac{P(B|A,C)P(A\cap C)}{P(B|C)P(C)}=\\
&=\frac{P(B|A,C)P(A|C)P(C)}{P(B|C)P(C)}=\\
&=\frac{P(B|A,C)P(A|C)}{P(B|C)}
\end{align}
$$